# Fetch the id of the current row by clicking on the html input button control inside the gridview, but without performing a postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I need help, i have a separate Template field in the grid-view in which i am displaying a pop up div which has separate fields to be filled inside another table, it requires me to pass "return false;" statement in the JavaScript function in order to maintain the form visibility which only happens when there is no post-back. So how can i fetch the id of the current row without post back.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Add Details"> 
<ItemTemplate>
<button id="myBtn" onclick="return false;">Add Details</button>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

and my HTML code is as follows

```html
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <div>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style4" >
                     </td>
                <td style="padding-right: 90px;" class="auto-style2">
                    <div id ="div1" >
                        <img id="Img1" src="~/images/icon_plus.png" width="20" runat="server" />
                   
                        <a title="Add Room Detail" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="addRow2('tblPets2')">Add Room Details
                           
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-left: 3%;">
        <table id="tblPets2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="custom-tablePopup">
            <tr>
                <th>Amenity Name</th>
                <th>Amenity Details</th>
                
                <th class="auto-style1"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="Name" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="Amenity Name"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Length" size="30" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Amenity Detail"/></td>
                <td class="auto-style1">
                   <img alt="" src="images/icon_minus.png"  style="width: 22px; cursor: pointer;" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var count = "1";
            function addRow2(in_tbl_name2) {
                var tbody = document.getElementById(in_tbl_name2).getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];
                // create row
                var row = document.createElement("TR");
                // create table cell 2
                var td1 = document.createElement("TD")
                var strHtml2 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Name\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Amenity Name\"/>";
                td1.innerHTML = strHtml2.replace(/!count!/g, count);
                // create table cell 3
                var td2 = document.createElement("TD")
                var strHtml3 = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"Length\" size=\"30\" maxlength=\"30\" placeholder=\"Enter Amenity Detail\"/>";
                td2.innerHTML = strHtml3.replace(/!count!/g, count);
                // create table cell 4
                
                var td5 = document.createElement("TD")
                var strHtml6 = "<img src=\"images/icon_minus.png\" onclick=\"delRow()\" style=\"width: 22px; cursor:pointer;\" />";
                td5.innerHTML = strHtml6.replace(/!count!/g, count);
                // append data to row
                row.appendChild(td1);
                row.appendChild(td2);
                row.appendChild(td5);
                count = parseInt(count) + 1;
                // add to count variable
                // append row to table
                tbody.appendChild(row);
            }
            function delRow() {
                var current = window.event.srcElement;
                //here we will delete the line
                while ((current = current.parentElement) && current.tagName != "TR");
                current.parentElement.removeChild(current);
            }
    </script>

    </div>
    <div>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>

  </div>
```

now the problem for me is that how should i fetch the id of the current row of whose HTML button i have clicked, that too without post back, because when post-back happens my popup form's visibility sustains only for a few seconds..

any help and ideas would be appreciated... thank you...

Comment: are you going to perform server side operation or client side javascript?

Comment: first step is by using client side javascript through which i have generated dynamic textboxes and then i have to save that information using ADO... or as till now i have thought to do so.

Comment: sorry not possible. you have complicated things..

Comment: you can pass your id in button tag using html5 custom tag. and get your id using javascript.

Comment: not possible. either do all in clientside and make an ajax Request using javascript or move everything into server side

Comment: i want the id of the current row not of the button ... @LateshtClick.com

Comment: @Aravind but the main problem here is the visibility of the popup form which will not sustain if post-back happens.. is there some way that the popup forms visibility sustains even after post-back, if that happens it is possible to fetch the current row

Answer (score 0):

Try this. The first button uses a value from the database. The second the row number of the GridView.

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <button id="myBtn" onclick="openModal('<%# Eval("field01").ToString() %>')" type="button">Add Details</button>

        <button id="myBtn" onclick="openModal(<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>)" type="button">Add Details</button>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And by using `type="button"` there will be no form post (PostBack).

Answer (score 0):

try with this code,

```
<button id="myBtn" OnClientClick="clickfun(YourId)" onclick="return false;">Add Details</button>
```

and then

```
function clickfun(id)
{
  // logic
}
```